# How to use git rebase to merge when local branch behind remote branch?

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a web project on the local branch, `dev`, and I currently complete my part. But here is the thing, my local branch is behind the remote branch `main`. Generally, I'd like to use `git merge` to merge remote branch. But this time, my manager ask me use `rebase` to merge, and I never `rebase` to merge remote branch. So, here I'm seeking help about the process that use `rebase` to merge when local branch behind remote branch.

Comment: 1. If your locally ```main``` branch is updated then run command ```git rebase main``` on you ```dev``` branch
2. Second way run command ```git pull origin main``` update directly from origin master

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First fetch all remote branches: `git fetch`
2. Then rebase your branch onto the remote main: `git rebase main dev`
3. If there are conflicts, resolve them, `git add`, `git rebase --continue`
4. (Force-) push your updated branch: `git push origin dev` or `git push origin +dev`

Alternatively, with git pull:

1. Switch to branch `git checkout dev`
2. `git pull --rebase origin main`
3. Push

Personally, I always prefer fetch + local operations, because it allows me to verify the remote history, before creating new commits.